# getting 500 Internal Server Error when hosting website on cyberpanel

Tags: django, hosting, django-deployment, cyber-panel

I am hosting django application on Cyberpanel. I have created website in cyberpanel and setup my django project. also changed vHost configuration. but in LIST WEBSITES getting this error

```
No Screenshot Available  
500 Internal server Error
```

[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtLXI.png)

I cant figure out how do I get rid of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyberpanel is using Statically's services to generate screenshots, it seems something wrong with Statically's server. Don't worry, it's not your Cyberpanel's problem.

Statically.io:
https://statically.io/

Demo: (Not working)
https://cdn.statically.io/screenshot/google.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).